# High rankings and impressions but very low clicks

Tags: seo, keywords, google-ranking, impressions, clicks

My website is ranking top on google (organic results) like in the first or second position and also i am getting high number of impressions for each keywords but the clicks rate is too low. What will be the reason for this?

Comment: How many impressions and how many clicks?  What rates are we actually talking about here?

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons for this.

It could mean that your website is ranking for searches that are not relevant to your actual website content, or at least to your content's representation in the SERPs. When the user looks at your title, description, URL, or rich results, they keep scrolling. This means in time, your rankings for those keywords will drop.

It could mean that the searcher's query is answered in the rich snippets or knowledge graph on the top or to the side of the organic results, courtesy of either your own or others' high ranking content, and the user never feels the need to click through to the website.

It could mean that Google Ads appear on top of the page - up to four of them stacked, or including shopping ads, depending on the query - and are drawing the clicks.

Other features, like local graph results and image search results, could also be eating up traffic. Or it's any combination of these reasons.

Once you pinpoint the reason, try playing with your on-page optimization to see how you can engineer where your pages appear in the SERPs.

Answer (score 1):

Just search as a user would do. Put yourself in a **typical searcher's shoes** and try to find what might make them skip over to other results over yours. There could be a variety of reasons including but not limited to:

1. Your title is not reflecting the searcher's **intent** accurately.
2. The title is too long and **cut off** by Search Engines, thus making it less clear to searchers.
3. **Competitors** have done a better job in answering the searcher's intent. May be their content including title and displayed snippet answer the query better than yours.

Never forget that at least 10 web pages compete with each other on the first page of results. The best among the 10 naturally gets the highest CTR. Eventually, the best page could move to the top as time goes by. Probably, CTR is a strong feedback signal for search engines.